# Issue in outputting data scraped using beautiful soup in two columns of csv using spamwriter.writerow

Tags: csv, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am scraping 2 sets of data from a website using beautiful soup and I want them to output in a csv file in 2 columns side by side. I am using spamwriter.writerow([x,y]) argument for this but I think because of some error in my recursion structure, I am getting the wrong output in my csv file. Below is the referred code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('Smartphones_20decv2.0.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')        
    for anchor in soup.findAll('a', {"class": "clickStreamSingleItem"},text=True):
        if anchor.string:
            print unicode(anchor.string).encode('utf8').strip()         

    for anchor1 in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"}):
        textcontent = u' '.join(anchor1.stripped_strings)
        if textcontent:
            print textcontent
            spamwriter.writerow([unicode(anchor.string).encode('utf8').strip(),textcontent])
```

Output which I am getting in csv is:

```
Samsung FocusÂ® 2 (Refurbished) $99.99
Samsung FocusÂ® 2 (Refurbished) $99.99 to $199.99 8 to 16 GB
Samsung FocusÂ® 2 (Refurbished) $0.99
Samsung FocusÂ® 2 (Refurbished) $0.99
Samsung FocusÂ® 2 (Refurbished) $149.99 to $349.99 16 to 64 GB
```

Problem is I am getting only 1 device name in column 1 instead of all while price is coming for all devices.
Please pardon my ignorance as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `anchor.string`, instead of `archor1`. `anchor` is the *last* item from the previous loop, instead of the item in the current loop.

Perhaps using clearer variable names would help avoid confusion here; use `singleitem` and `gridprice` perhaps?

It could be I misunderstood though and you want to combine each `anchor1` with a corresponding `anchor`. You'll have to loop over them together, perhaps using `zip()`:

```
items = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "clickStreamSingleItem"},text=True)
prices = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"})
for item, price in zip(items, prices):
    textcontent = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
    if textcontent:
        print textcontent
        spamwriter.writerow([unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').strip(),textcontent])
```

*Normally* it should be easier to loop over the parent table row instead, then find the cells within that row within a loop. But the `zip()` should work too, provided the `clickStreamSingleItem` cells line up with the `listGrid-price` matches.

Comment: Can you help me in pinpointing the changes to be made in code so that my output is w/o any special characters? Eg. I want this name "Samsung RugbyÂ® Smart" to be as "Samsung Rugby Smart" .

Comment: @user1915050: You are seeing the latin-1 interpretation of your UTF-8 character. Open the file with an editor that can read UTF-8 and you'll see that it is the `®` character instead. It's unicode codepoint `\u00AE` is encoded to `\xC2\xAE` in UTF-8, and when your file viewer assumes it's latin-1 text instead it'll show `Â` for the `\xC2` byte.

Comment: Okay, Can you help me in invoking "on click event" for a button in javascript. Detailed problem is explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967454/issues-with-invoking-on-click-event-on-the-html-page-using-beautiful-soup-in-p

Comment: Is there a way to remove these special characters from output csv using some method in python code?

Comment: @user1915050: You could encode to `ASCII` with `errors` set to `ignore`; you'll remove all accents too then though: `unicode(item.string).encode('ascii', 'ignore')`; `ignore` tries to encode everything to ASCII and will skip anything that doesn't 'fit'.