# How to simulate a button click in a request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

**Please do not close this question - this is not a duplicate. I need to click the button using Python requests, not Selenium, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385156)**

I am trying to scrape [Reverso Context translation examples page](https://context.reverso.net/translation/russian-english/cat). And I have a problem: I can get only 20 examples and then I need to click the "Display more examples" button **lots of times while it exists on the page** to get the full results list. It can simply be done using a web browser, but how can I do it with Python Requests library?

I looked at the button's HTML code, but I couldn't find an `onclick` attribute to look at JS script attached to it, and I don't understand what request I need to send:

```
<button id="load-more-examples" class="button load-more " data-default-size="14px">Display more examples</button>
```

And here is my Python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


with requests.Session() as session:  # Create a Session
    # Log in
    login_url = 'https://account.reverso.net/login/context.reverso.net/it?utm_source=contextweb&utm_medium=usertopmenu&utm_campaign=login'
    session.post(login_url, "Email=reverso.scraping@yahoo.com&Password=sample",
           headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0", "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

    # Get the HTML
    html_text = session.get("https://context.reverso.net/translation/russian-english/cat", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}).content

    # And scrape it
    for word_pair in BeautifulSoup(html_text).find_all("div", id=re.compile("^OPENSUBTITLES")):
        print(word_pair.find("div", class_="src ltr").text.strip(), "=", word_pair.find("div", class_="trg ltr").text.strip())
```

**Note:** **you need to log in**, otherwise it will show only first 10 examples and will not show the button. You may use this **real** authentication data:
**E-mail:** reverso.scraping@yahoo.com

**Password:** sample

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invoking onclick event with beautifulsoup python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385156/invoking-onclick-event-with-beautifulsoup-python)

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, though unfortunately this doesn't answer my question

Comment: I use requests, and they use selenium webdriver

Comment: you can't do that with requests https://stackoverflow.com/a/37167063/8619959

Comment: _It can simply be done using a web browser, but how can I do it with Python Requests library?_ You can't, Requests does not execute JavaScript or anything like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Clicking" button with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164675/clicking-button-with-requests)

Comment: How does the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385156/invoking-onclick-event-with-beautifulsoup-python) which @evgenifotia shared not answer the question, by the way?

Comment: @evgenifotia, thank you very much for your answer! :) I have a very good day today and I could do it with `requests`. I have answered this question below.

Comment: @AMC, thank you very much for your answer! :) I agree with you, that it can't execute JS, but in some cases (like this one, for example), it is possible to explore the browser's behavior in more detail: get the requests it sends and try to do the same thing using Python `requests` (I have described how to do this in more detail in the answer below).

Comment: _in some cases (like this one, for example), it is possible to explore the browser's behavior in more detail: get the requests it sends and try to do the same thing using Python requests_ Of course, but I wouldn't call that _simulating a button press_.

Comment: @AMC, considering the link to the question you gave, it was very useful for me - it put the idea to explore the browser's behavior into my head. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @AMC, I think you are right)

Comment: @AMC, and considering the first question which evgenfotia gave, it is very useful, but not in my case, because my app shouldn't have any dependencies (except Python site-packages which can be installed using `pip`). And `Selenium`, in contradistinction to `requests`, is browser-dependent and requires the chrome-driver to be installed manually by the user.

Comment: @DemianWolf You're welcome, I'm glad you got lucky and were able to find a way to make the requests directly!

Comment: @DemianWolf Do you not count something as a dependency if it can be installed with pip, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @AMC, I was very glad to talk to you :)

Comment: @AMC, no, I count it as a dependency. I have written **(except** Python...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that gets all the example sentences using `requests` and removes all the HTML tags from them using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


headers = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Length": "96",
    "Origin": "https://context.reverso.net",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Referer": "https://context.reverso.net/^%^D0^%^BF^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^80^%^D0^%^B5^%^D0^%^B2^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B4/^%^D0^%^B0^%^D0^%^BD^%^D0^%^B3^%^D0^%^BB^%^D0^%^B8^%^D0^%^B9^%^D1^%^81^%^D0^%^BA^%^D0^%^B8^%^D0^%^B9-^%^D1^%^80^%^D1^%^83^%^D1^%^81^%^D1^%^81^%^D0^%^BA^%^D0^%^B8^%^D0^%^B9/cat",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
}

data = {
    "source_text": "cat",
    "target_text": "",
    "source_lang": "en",
    "target_lang": "ru",
    "npage": 1,
    "mode": 0
}

npages = requests.post("https://context.reverso.net/bst-query-service", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data)).json()["npages"]
for npage in range(1, npages + 1):
    data["npage"] = npage
    page = requests.post("https://context.reverso.net/bst-query-service", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data)).json()["list"]
    for word in page:
        print(BeautifulSoup(word["s_text"]).text, "=", BeautifulSoup(word["t_text"]).text)
```

At first, I got the request from the Google Chrome DevTools:

1. Pressed **F12** key to enter it and selected the Network Tab
2. Clicked the "Display more examples" button
3. Found the last request ("bst-query-service")
4. Right-clicked it and selected **Copy > Copy as cURL (cmd)**

Then, I opened [this online-tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/), insert the copied cURL to the textbox on the left and copied the output on the right (use **Ctrl-C** hotkey for this, otherwise it may not work).

After that I inserted it to the IDE and:

1. Removed the `cookies` dict - it is not necessary here
2. **Important: Rewrote the `data` string as a Python dictionary and wrapped it with `json.dumps(data)`, otherwise, it returned a request with empty words list.**
3. Added a script, that: gets a number of times to fetch the words ("pages") and created a `for` loop that gets words this number of times and prints them without HTML tags (using BeautifulSoup)

**UPD:**
For those, who visited the question to learn how to work with Reverso Context (not just to simulate a button click request on other website) there is a Python wrapper for Reverso API released: [Reverso-API](https://pypi.org/project/Reverso-API/). It can do the same thing as above but much simpler:

```
from reverso_api.context import ReversoContextAPI


api = ReversoContextAPI("cat", "", "en", "ru")
for source, target in api.get_examples_pair_by_pair():
    print(highlight_example(source.text), "==", highlight_example(target.text))
```